# Typescript/Javascript: Recursive method to get the value of a key

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I have a recursive method which takes a key as input and iterates over an array of objects to fetch the value of that key.

```
findKeyFun(passedKey: string): string {
    let tempVal = null;
    for(let i=0; i< this.valueArray.length; i++) {
      if(this.valueArray[i].children) {
        for(let j=0; j< this.valueArray[i].children.length; j++) {
          if(this.valueArray[i].children[j].children) {
            for(let k=0; k<this.valueArray[i].children[j].children.length; k++){
              if(this.valueArray[i].children[j].children[k].key==passedKey){
                tempVal = this.valueArray[i].children[j].children[k].value;
                return tempVal;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return tempVal;
  }
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fDhNpEpDzaCq34FNtBOk?p=preview)

But too many `for` loops are involved in this piece of code. How can I make this recursive method irrespective of the position of the key?

Comment: your code is kinda hard to follow. what is the structure of your data?

Comment: @aeid It's an array of objects and each object may or may not have children/grandchildren

Comment: recursion would work find but  `array.reduce`  is much better I think

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to pass the object around that contains the children and either return null or the found value?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small sample for you.

The container class is probably similar to the data structure that you are using. It's got a key and an array of children.

The algorithm you are using in your question is very problematic. It only searches the keys of children of children of the initial object. If the initial object has the correct key, it can still return null.

I've implemented a depth first search for you instead.
This should return the correct child at any place in the hierarchy.

```
class Container{
    key: string;
    children: Container[];
}

function searchKey(container: Container, key:string){
    if (container.key == key) {
        return container;
    }
    else if (container.children.length>0){
        for (var child of container.children) {
            var found = searchKey(child, key);
            if (found != null) {
                return found
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

I would advise you to read up on this type of algorithm.

Here is a nice [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) article.

Comment: This works with an object array({ [ ] }). But if the input is an Array of objects([ { } ]), how to handle it? For example - function searchKey(container: Container[ ], key:string){ }